# how to show a column with a specific id from a database in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

So I have tried examples from internet and edited this question ,so want to select `title`,and `descrIption` column in a specific id from `posts` table from database named `laravel` in my website so that it can integrate with my bootstrap.
I am using laravel

Here are some lines in the view welcome.blade.php with my bootstrap

```php
<div class="blog-thumb">
    <img src="asset/img/blog/1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
@foreach($posts1 as $post)
<h3>{{ $post->title }}</h3>
<p>{!! \Illuminate\Support\Str::words($post->description, 50, '...') !!}</p>
@endforeach

</div>
<div class="blog-thumb">
    <img src="asset/img/blog/2.jpg" alt="">
</div>
@foreach($posts2 as $post) 
<h3>{{ $post->title }}</h3>
<p>{!! \Illuminate\Support\Str::words($post->description, 50, '...') !!}</p>
@endforeach

</div>
```

here is the PostController that i try

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex1() {
        $posts1 = Post::find(1);
    }
    public function getIndex2() {
        $posts2 = Post::find(2);
    }
    public function getIndex3() {
        $posts3 = Post::find(3);
    }
```

and this is the routes

```
Route::get('/',function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/', 'PostController@getIndex1')->name('index1');
Route::get('/', 'PostController@getIndex2')->name('index2');
Route::get('/', 'PostController@getIndex3')->name('index3');
```

but now it show only white page

Comment: Hi Michael. That is quite a lot of questions! but... there is a great resource for starting Laravel. Check out. https://laracasts.com/skills/laravel, there are a bunch of free videos which talk you through step by step on how to get started. Good luck!

Comment: @MichaelAbraham could you please mark my answer as the answer if it matches to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can try for routes as folloe

```
Route::resource('posts','PostsController');
```

If you want to fetch data for a specific ID just use

```
public function getIndex($id){
   $uniquePost = Post::findOrFail($id);
}
```

And compact this with the view .